# Drill down so that each column in visualization is represented by a column in data set

Tags: powerbi

I have the below PowerBI model that is functioning correctly on the surface.
However, I need to drill down into a data set and I cannot get it to display properly.

I have the attached visualization and data set.

[image]
[image]

Column 11 represents February. I would like to display the total revenue and quantity depending on which filter is used in a single column. Column 12 would be March and so on.

How would I accomplish this?

I have tried using youtube and existing forumns but have had no such luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your ask isn't clear. You want to add a drill down to the bar chart?

You should reshape your data and perhaps give more meaningful column names.
Suggest you also unpivot your data so you have a structure similar to:

| Product Line | Metric | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ProductLine1 | Rev | 2023-02-01 |
| ProductLine1 | Qty | 2023-02-01 |

Comment: Yes, I would like to drill down to the bar chart. Unfortunately, the month column contains all quantitative data for that month.